# How to fill column' value with another column and keep existing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe with two column`['c1','c2']`, and I want to fill `c2` with its corresponding `c1` if exist, also if `c1` already have a value keep it don't change it with `c2`. Here is an example:

input

```
c1             c2
HP_0003470  
HP_8362789    HP_0093723
              MP_0000231
              MP_0000231
```

output

```
c1             c2
HP_0003470  
HP_8362789    HP_0093723
MP_0000231    MP_0000231
MP_0000231    MP_0000231
```

It's look easy, but I'm beginner in python :(
Any help please.

Comment: Are the empty rows, blanks strings `''`or `NAN`s?

Comment: @Zero it's empty string ' '

Comment: @ScottBoston I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['c1'].eq(''), 'c1'] = df['c2']`

Comment: @SaraWasl, It's difficult to tell exactly what your DataFrame values are when you just paste a DataFrame with empty values or missing values. Using `df.to_dict()` will yield: `{'c1': {0: 'HP_0003470', 1: 'MP_0000231', 2: '', 3: ''},...` making it clear how they are truly represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so:

```
df['c1'] = df['c1'].replace('',np.NaN).fillna(df['c2'])
df['c2'] = df['c2'].replace('',np.NaN).fillna(df['c1'])
```

Output:

```
           c1          c2
0  HP_0003470  HP_0003470
1  HP_8362789  HP_0093723
2  MP_0000231  MP_0000231
3  MP_0000231  MP_0000231
```

Comment: That's work for me :) Thank you

Comment: @SaraWasl You are welcome! :)